# How do I restart my program automatically (forever) every few hours?

Tags: python, api, rest

I have a program that I need to be active (running) for about a week.

This program listens to a website's feed and decides what to do based on each signal it receives. However, I have noticed that the programs pauses (stops without no errors or signs after about 8 hours of running) and will not resume until ctrl+c and restarted. Given there is no limit on the amount of time that a python script can run, how can I make sure that my program is restarted, say, every five hours, so I can make sure it will not stop working?

My program uses  `import requests` and its classes to connect to a REST API feed.

The following is the part of the program that listens the feed.

```
def connect():
    domain = 'x'
    access_token = 'x'
    account_id = 'x'
    instruments = 'x'

    try:
        # Tries to connect, if unsuccessful it will close the connection.
        s = requests.Session()
        url = "https://" + domain + "/v1/prices"
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token, }
        params = {'instruments': instruments, 'accountId' : account_id}
        req = requests.Request('GET', url, headers=headers, params=params)
        pre = req.prepare()
        resp = s.send(pre, stream=True, verify=True)
        return resp
    except Exception as e:
        s.close()
        print "Caught exception when connecting to stream\n" + str(e)


def demo(display_heartbeat):
    response = connect()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print response.text
        return
    for line in response.iter_lines(1):
        if line:
            try:
                msg = json.loads(line)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                return

            if display_heartbeat:
                print line
            else:
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    parser.json_parser(msg)


def main():
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-b", "--displayHeartBeat", dest="verbose", action="store_true",
                      help="Display HeartBeat in streaming data")
    display_heartbeat = False
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) > 1:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
    if options.verbose:
        display_heartbeat = True
    demo(display_heartbeat)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Restart the script every 2 hours?

Comment: Very good suggestion. But why? Why should I not be able to run the program for more than 8 hours? It is pissing me off.

Comment: You probably have a mistake in your program. Can you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: 8 hours that's a fair working day.  Scripts are people too.

Comment: Most likely some sort of resource leak that accumulates over time.  But, without code, that's just a guess.

Comment: I can't. It's more of an application now. It has gotten a bit complex. However,  the pseudo code is something like. Wait for tick stream, if there was any, do something, and wait for the next tick.

Comment: Well, if you won't give us the code, how do you expect us to help you debug  it?

Comment: I was more asking if something UNRELATED to my code might be happening, something common knowledge to python people that I may not be aware of. To be fair, I don't think there is anything wrong with my code. It's more of a something with either default REST connection or Python script in general.

Comment: @Janekmuric can you kindly write an answer that can restart the script every 2 hours?

Comment: python have no any limitation on working  certain amount of time, so the problem is either in your code or in the system when the script runs.

Comment: @Petr Good to know that. I will update my question now.

Comment: @auryndb Did you check how many program uses CPU and memory when it pauses.

Comment: @auryndb If someone wrote you a script to restart every x hours wouldnt that script then need a script to restart it every y hours and that script would need a script to restart every z hours and so on. Best to just find the problem instead of doing janky workarounds where you don't understand what is actually wrong.

Comment: @Petr I haven't. you mean if my program is still using CPU and memory or you suggest other programs are using so much CPU that there is none left for my script. But I will look at it this time. I'm looking for something bullet proof though, I want to leave the program for days and not look at it. I don't want to worry about it stopping working.

Comment: @Jacobr365 you are right!

Comment: I posted the main code! that listen to the STREAM REST API.

Comment: @auryndb I would like to say, as already was noticed, that program can contains resources leaks that accumulates over time

Comment: So if I don't want to change the code, then restarting the program would be the answer? Restarting it before resources leaking accumulate to a certain threshold. @Petr which part of the code is leaking btw?

Comment: @auryndb That is not a good way to do it. As the system the script is running on changes, programs added or removed or whatever the threshold could change so if the issue is resource leaks they should be plugged. It will save you a lot of trouble in the future to fix bugs now while code is fresh in your mind.

Comment: I didn't notice anything suspicious. Can you show how you implemented rerun script with time?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to delete the question. I think the problem is neither python nor my program but the website closes the connection.

Comment: I'd use cron if I needed brute force it.

Comment: @auryndb The idea is the script should get an error on closing connection. This would then create the session again. But I never used requests, so I can't be sure.

Comment: This question closed while I was writing an answer, so here it is: http://pastebin.com/Vf8NFwVn

Comment: @AlexHall: seems like a solution. Hopefully some people will vote to reopen. Alternatively, you could try to catch a SocketError or similar...

Comment: @auryndb: could you post the Exception message output?